# Does spring injects dependencies of a class created manually

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have an class's similar to this:

```
 @Controller
 class A{
   @Autowired
   private B b;
    ....
 }
```

class B:

```
 @Service
 class B{
 ....
 }
```

i am woring in a spring project. If i initialize class A manually like this:

```
A a= new A();
```

Will spring be able to inject B to my class. This aren't my real classes, but i have similar scenario, and am trying to run a unit test with spring test. I initialize the object manually as the above. But spring is complaining for NullPointerException. I am not used spring for long time and I am little bit confused. Can any body confirm's me if spring will still inject the dependency if i initialize the class?

Comment: Simple answer: of course not, if Spring isn't involved in instantiation it has no chance to process dependencies. There are ways around this.

Comment: Once you call "new", all bets are off.  Spring is out of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring won't inject dependencies if you initialize the class. It only inject if the class is initialized by its container.

This may help you: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html